# Install files to a users home directory using Iceberg (osx)?

Tags: macos, package

I'm new to using Iceberg, and making packages in general. I added the files I want installed on the users machine, but am not sure how to add them to the users home directory. When I build the package it ads them to literal structure created in the Files tab. I search all over the net and found some documents that reference creating a symbolic link via a script. I'm extremely new to creating scripts, but tried that as well by creating a preflight.txt with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
ln -s $HOME "/Movies/My\ Folder/Subfolder"
exit 0
```

I also tried:

```
#!/bin/sh
ln -s "/Movies/My\ Folder/Subfolder" "$HOME/Movies/My\ Folder/Subfolder"
exit 0
```

I'm not sure i'm headed down the right path here. Or if it's just a simple mistake. One more piece of information, the user may or may not have a "My Folder" folder on their drive already.

Answer (score 1):

Packages install to the system, not to home directories. If your application needs to create objects in the user's home directory, it should do so itself when it is first launched, not when it is installed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's not an application I'm trying to install, they are template files that live in the Movies folder in the users home directory. Could this be achieved by using a script, or is there a better way? I'm totally lost here. Thank you again for your assistance.

Comment: If there is no application involved, I'm confused as to why you're trying to build an Installer package. If you're only distributing data files, it'd be more appropriate to distribute them as a zip archive (or similar) and have the user put them in place manually.

Comment: They are template files for Final Cut Pro, unfortunately many users have issues with the instruction of drag and drop <grin>.

After 3 days of trial and error, I've come up with a solution... but would like to ask you if this is a proper work around, see next response for my work-around as there wasn't enough space to write it here.

Comment: Basically I have a preflight script which creates the directory for the template files if it doesn't currently exist. Then I use a postflight script to Move the files from the /Application directory over to the directory where I need them to reside. After doing that, I remove the directories inside the /Application directory to clean things up. I've tested it on another machine and it seems to work as needed. But is this the right way?

Comment: Probably not. Even as described, an installer package will end up requiring administrator privileges, and will leave your template tiles with weird permissions. You're probably better off writing a Applescript applet or something to move the files into place, if you really must have a double-clickable "installer".

Comment: I appreciate your time. However, I'm confused. I've seen other companies use pkg's to install templates like the ones I'm providing. Is it just bad practice? I haven't seen any with AppleScripts inside dmg's.